# How to remove multiple first characters using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have string `string A = "... :-ggw..-:p";`

using regex: `string B = Regex.Replace(A, @"^\.+|:|-|", "").Trim();`

My Output is`ggw..p`.

What I want is `ggw..-:p`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a character class with your symbols and whitespace shorthand character class:

```
string B = Regex.Replace(A, @"^[.:\s-]+", "");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B.%3A%5Cs-%5D%2B&i=...%20%3A-ggw..-%3Ap)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[.:\s-]+` - one or more characters defined in the character class.

Note that there is no need escaping `.` inside `[...]`. The `-` does not have to be escaped since it is at the end of the character class.

Comment: Well \s would still have to be inside the character class, or any \s left of `.`, `:` or `-` would stop those from being replaced.

Comment: Yes, it is something I also understood a moment ago. and logged in from a mobile to remove that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

A regex isn't necessary if you only want to trim specific characters from the start of a string.  `System.String.TrimStart()` will do the job:

```
var source = "... :-ggw..-:p";
var charsToTrim = " .:-".ToCharArray();
var result = source.TrimStart(charsToTrim);
Console.WriteLine(result);

// Result is 'ggw..-:p'
```